# Add only highest level of certification to array

Tags: php, arrays

Not quite sure how to ask this question, but here it goes:

I have three different levels of certification (LPCS, LPC, LPCA) on an old system that I need to add to a new system that better differentiates the various levels (is_certification).

I've create an array that will capture the information based upon the certification level. I can add them to the array, but my goal is to add the highest level of certification they've completed. For example, a LPCS is higher than an LPC which is higher than a LPCA. If they've gone through all the courses, I only want the LPCS added to the array, or if they have only completed the LPC, I don't want the LPCA to show in the array.

Suggestions and help greatly appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
$oldsystem_certs = array();
foreach ($old_expired_cert as $cert){
    if ((strpos($cert->product, 'LPCS') == True) || (strpos($cert->product, 'LPC') == True) || (strpos($cert->product, 'LPCA') == True) && $cert->is_certification==0){
        $at = strtotime(certification_end($cert));
        $bt = strtotime(date("2015-04-15"));
        if($at >= $bt){
        }else{
                array_push($oldsystem_certs, $cert);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the format of `$cert->product`? Why are you using `strpos` instead of simply `$cert->product == "LPCS"`?

Comment: I have to pull the content out by its title. No other way to distinguish it from any other certification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test for each substring separately. You can then map them to a numeric certification level to make testing for the highest easier. Note that you have to check `LPC` last, because it's a substring of the other certificate names.

```
$cert_levels = array('LPCS' => 3, 'LPCA' => 1, 'LPC' => 2);

$highest_cert_level = 0;
$highest_cert = null;
$at = null;
foreach ($old_expired_cert as $cert) {
    $prod = $cert->product;
    $cert_level = 0;
    foreach ($cert_levels as $certname => $level) {
        if (strpos($prod, $certname) !== false)) {
            if ($level > $highest_cert_level) {
                $highest_cert_level = $level;
                $highest_cert = $cert;
                $at = strtotime(certification_end($cert));
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
$bt = strtotime(date("2015-04-15"));
if ($highest_cert && $at < $bt) {
    $oldsystem_array[] = $highest_cert;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/avTmHT)

Comment: Looks good, but I don't see how you are identifying these three certifications from the rest (30+ certifications). Where would you put the search of product title (strpos($cert->product, 'LPCS') ?

Comment: I wrote the answer before I understood why you were using `strpos`, it assumes `product` is just the certification name.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `strpos` instead of an exact match.

Comment: Implemented the code and ran it for someone with an LPC and it only shows their LPCA.